# Get value of element in xml - always returning null

Tags: java, xml

I have an `XML` file as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<coffeeOrder>
    <addition>null</addition>
    <cost>3.0</cost>
    <id>1</id>
    <links>http://localhost:9080/cs9322.ass2/rest/payment/1</links>
    <status>cancelled</status>
    <type>espresso</type>
</coffeeOrder>
```

I am trying to retrieve the `value` of `status`.

Currently I have the following:

```
try {
    Document document = loadXMLFromString(orderXML);
    NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
    // Cycle through nodes, until "status" or "paymentType" element found
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {                      
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {  
            Element elem = (Element) node;

            System.out.println(orderXML);
            System.out.println(elem.toString());

            if (type.equals("order") && elem.getNodeName().equals("status")){
                status = elem.getNodeValue();
            } else if(type.equals("payment") && elem.getNodeName().equals("paymentType")){                      
                status = elem.getNodeValue();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I am finding that I am constantly getting `null`.

```
System.out.println(elem.toString());
```

returns

```
[status: null]
```

even though

```
System.out.println(orderXML);
```

shows that the `status` is not `null`

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getTextContent` method instead of `getNodeValue`. See documentation on [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) class.